# How can retrieve clustering calcualtion within class?

Tags: python, pandas, class, scikit-learn, k-means

I'm experimenting with KM-based algorithm so-called ODKM which uses [KMeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#k-means) clustering algorithm.

I want to retrieve [clustering info](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) `cluster_centers_`, `labels_` `cluster_score`, `effect`, `dist` within `class ODKM` elegantly.

```py
import math
from math import pow
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans


class ODKM:
    
    def __init__(self,n_clusters=15,effectiveness=500,max_iter=2):
        self.n_clusters=n_clusters
        self.effectiveness=effectiveness
        self.max_iter=max_iter
        self.kmeans = {}
        self.cluster_score = {}
        
    def fit(self, data):
        length = len(data)
        for column in data.columns:
            kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=self.n_clusters,max_iter=self.max_iter)
            self.kmeans[column]=kmeans
            kmeans.fit(data[column].values.reshape(-1,1))
            assign = pd.DataFrame(kmeans.predict(data[column].values.reshape(-1,1)),columns=['cluster'])
            cluster_score=assign.groupby('cluster').apply(len).apply(lambda x:x/length)
            ratio=cluster_score.copy()
        
            sorted_centers = sorted(kmeans.cluster_centers_)
            max_distance = ( sorted_centers[-1] - sorted_centers[0] )[ 0 ]
        
            for i in range(self.n_clusters):
                for k in range(self.n_clusters):
                    if i != k:
                        dist = np.abs(kmeans.cluster_centers_[i] - kmeans.cluster_centers_[k])/max_distance
                        effect = ratio[k]*(1/pow(self.effectiveness,dist))
                        cluster_score[i] = cluster_score[i]+effect
                        
            self.cluster_score[column] = cluster_score
                    
    def predict(self, data):
        length = len(data)
        score_array = np.zeros(length)
        for column in data.columns:
            kmeans = self.kmeans[ column ]
            cluster_score = self.cluster_score[ column ]
            
            assign = kmeans.predict( data[ column ].values.reshape(-1,1) )
            #print(assign)
            
            for i in range(length):
                score_array[i] = score_array[i] + math.log10( cluster_score[assign[i]] )
            
        return score_array
    
    def fit_predict(self,data):
        self.fit(data)
        return self.predict(data)
```

test the results:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'attr1':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,15],
                         'attr2':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,13,13,13,14,15]})


odkm_model = ODKM(n_clusters=3, max_iter=1)
result = odkm_model.fit_predict(df)

df['ODKM_Score']= result 
df

#for i in result:
#    print(round(i,2))

#results
#-0.51, -0.51 , -0.51 , -0.51, -0.51, -0.51, -0.51, -0.51, -0.51, -0.51, -0.51, -0.51, -0.51
#-0.78, -0.78, -0.78, -0.78, -0.78, -0.78, -0.78
#-0.99, -0.99, -0.99, -0.99
#-1.99
```

So question is: Is there any elegant way I can include clustering info and return it when I run the `class ODKM` and get reflect results of `@class ODKM` like how we do `df['ODKM_Score']= result` for `df['Cluster_labels']= result`, `df['Cluster_centers']= result`, `df['cluster_score']= result` to have all info within main dataframe `df` and pave the way visualization of clustering results.

normally without class method scripting I would do this using `km.cluster_centers_` and `km.cluster_centers_`:

```py
n_clusters=3

km = KMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=n_clusters).fit(df[['Score']])

counts = np.bincount(km.labels_)

for center, count, label in zip(km.cluster_centers_, counts, range(n_clusters)):
    print(center, count)
    plt.bar(center, count, width=0.2, label=label)
```

but I'm wondering if I could collect this clustering info after fit and transform model maybe define a function at the end of class named `KM_summary`:

- predicted cluster labels `km.labels_`
- cluster centers `km.cluster_centers_`
- `dist`, `effect`, `cluster_score` from 2nd function `def fit(self, data):`
- `score_array` from 3nd function `def predict(self, data):`

[image: img]

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you define an attribute `self.KM_summary=None` in the `__init__` and then fill it with what you want in `predict` ?

Comment: tbh it didn't cross my mind but if you can form your answer it would be great.

Comment: What is is `ODKM`? Do `cluster_centers_`, `labels_ `, `cluster_score`, `effect`, `dist` come from fitted `KMeans` or specific to `ODKM`?

Comment: ODKM is an unsupervised outlier detection* on top of the [KMeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) clustering algorithm, which is scripted in form of a class. The first two elements are retrievable from `KMeans` directly based on its document but the last three elements are designed for some calculation to generate `ODKM_Score` while fitting `KMeans`. Please feel free to check it out this [Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zjte6pU9YxtfEoPBa-gyjaogLdLTUkWw?usp=sharing) and comment next to cells for quick debugging.

Comment: If `ODKM` is purely an extension of `KMeans`, you probably want to subclass and extend methods - something like `class ODKM(KMeans)`.   Using this, you get the `KMeans` api for free (and can overwrite anything as needed).

Comment: @anon01 thanks for your input please let me know if you can form your solution in form of *answer*. You can check\test on [Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zjte6pU9YxtfEoPBa-gyjaogLdLTUkWw?usp=sharing) for quick debugging\implementation.

Comment: @anon01 I can update the bounty again if you have the concrete solution!